# Drop Down issue - Mobile browser based app on IOS 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ios, ios7

I have a browser based mobile app which works fine on all browsers, devices except for IOS 7.

In IOS 7 on emulator and Iphone which has IOS 7 what i am seeing is dropdown first value is not getting selected, when i select second item and then go to first item it works, but when i directly select the first item in the list it does not work.

I am clearing all the selected attributes before, here is the code:

```
$("select").attr('selectedIndex', '-1').find("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
$("select").val([]);
```

and then on change function i do this:

```
   $('select').live('change',function() {
        $(this).parent().children('div').html($(this).find('option:selected').text());
        $(this).parent().children('div').removeClass('place_holder_color');
    });
```

this is working fine on all browsers and devices except IOS 7

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you guys think it can be jquery version issue as i am using old jquery 1.6.4. Do let me know.

Answer (score -1):

iOS7 upgrade caused all dropdown options to fail.  developers need to go back and look at all instances --- registration screens, feature selection, and find an easier way to redesign that does not create constant rewrites because Apple wants a new look.  Forcing extra work on developers for no benefit to anyone.

Comment: Hi Mickey, thanks for your answer. What ever you mentioned here is there any article which states that ? Please let me know.